# WordPress post search with ignoring apostrophe

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to search posts in `wp_posts` table

```
$searchValue = $request->get_param("s");
$wpQueryPosts = new \WP_Query([
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'cat'           => 9,
            's' => $searchValue,
]);

$postsPosts = $wpQueryPosts->get_posts();
```

The problem is when I search word with apostrophe it's not searched properly. If I search `don` I get proper results, when I search `don't` I don't get any results. Even though I know there are posts with `don't` in their title and content. I found many similar questions but none of them has any clear answer.

Also how can I get same results for both `dont` and `don't`

the problem is that if word in database contains apostrophe, it doesn't appear in results

Comment: What if you try to sanitize the input first? Something like  `$searchValue = sanitize_text_field($searchValue)`; or `$searchValue = urldecode($searchValue)`

Comment: the problem is that if word in database contains apostrophe, it doesn't appear in results

Comment: Then please put that in your question above. In your original post you say the problem is when query have apostrophe then it doesn't show, not the database.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

`$searchValue = html_entity_decode( $searchValue, ENT_QUOTES );`